# how to array random char java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to put several randomly characters in an array and finally be able to compare them with user inputs.
like this:

```
String[] arr={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
random:"ABDE"
```

then get input from user and compare with random.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is unclear what problem do you have. Please rephrase your question and format your code.

Comment: Is it intentional that the example `ABDE` is still ordered alphabetically, or would you consider `BDAE` different?

Comment: It is between ABDE and BDAE different